# Access row data in material table header Cell

Tags: angular, angular-material

To access the data of current row in a column, we can use following code:

```
 <mat-cell *matCellDef="let rowdata">{{rowdata.name}}</mat-cell>
```

But I need to access data on header row. Can we do that ? Like this

```
<mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef="let rowdata" >{{rowdata}}</mat-header-cell>
```

Comment: Please can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: I do have a valid case where I need to access row data in "mat-header-cell". I need to use "sticky" property of mat-header-cell. So I want to define more than one header row and hence to show data I need to access row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible - and would not make sense. You have `0...n` cells, so `rowdata` takes the value of each element for each cell. But you only have one table header. The only sensible data it could give you there is an array containing all `rowdata`.

You could, however, access the underlying `dataSource` you are passing in directly.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="someColName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{dataSource[0].name}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let rowdata"> {{rowdata.name}} </td>
  </ng-container
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit, but `dataSource` has no `data` property, according to the API https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples but is a simple array.

Comment: the data is the array of elements which  you provided in initialization

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the `dataSource` you are passing via `[dataSource]="dataSource"` has to be an array, not an object containing a `data` property. That `dataSource` is the one I'm referring to here. Referencing one of the examples: `data: PeriodicElement[] = ELEMENT_DATA;` in component and `[dataSource]="data"` in template.

Comment: Ah sorry you are correct, I mean when you are define the dataSource by this way `dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);` in this case you need to get the elements by `dataSource.data[0].name`. Please have a look on the stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzjzvx and sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: Ahh okay, I didn't know about that method. Thanks for the clarification! :)

Comment: I do have a valid case where I need to access row data in "mat-header-cell". I need to use "sticky" property of mat-header-cell. So I want to define more than one header row and hence to show data I need to access row.

Comment: In that case it might be easier to hold the sticky items in a different array and just `*ngFor` over them in the `mat-header-cell`. You just need to be aware of the fact that the `<mat-table>` is not supporting this officially and you will be building a kind of workaround that might even break when updating.